# How to use non-volatile memory on the LGT8F328P board?

Tags: eeprom

Where can I get a library for working with memory?
I need to write the value to memory only when it is updated, and not constantly. How to do it?

```
 #include <EEPROM.h>
    void setup()
    {
    int x, r;
    }
    
    void loop()
    {
    x = analogRead(A0);
    EEPROM.write(x);
    r = EEPROM.read(x);
    }
```